# Using row number to create a 0/1 column in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in my dataset for when 'death_code' contains an 'I' (could be I001-I100) then it would return a 1, otherwise it would return a 0

```
death_code
I099
E045
T054
I065
I022
```

I have used grepl to search for rows in a variable which contain 'I' and saved the row numbers

```
rows<-which(grepl('I', fulldata$deathcode))
```

However I now want to assign a 1 to these rows in a new column and I cannot workout how to do this.

This is what I anticipate the data to look like

```
death_code  CVD_death
I099.       1
E045.       0
T054.       0
I065.       1
I022.       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `which`, use `as.integer` on the `grepl` result - TRUE/FALSE will be converted to 1/0.

```
fulldata$CVD_death <- as.integer(grepl("I", fulldata$deathcode))
```

Alternately, you could do it with `which` by setting all values in the column to 0, and then setting the `which` values to 1:

```
fulldata$CVD_death <- 0
fulldata$CVD_death[which(grepl("I", fulldata$deathcode))] <- 1
```

Comment: Great, much simpler than what I was trying to attempt! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using stringr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(CVD_death = case_when(str_detect(death_code, '^I\\d{3}') ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  death_code CVD_death
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 I099               1
2 E045               0
3 T054               0
4 I065               1
5 I022               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `+` to convert the logical to `integer`

```
 fulldata$CVD_death <- +(grepl("I", fulldata$deathcode))
```